# Return object from javascript to silverlight

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Here are the steps I'd like to take:

1) User enters search term into box in silverlight, then presses enter

2) Search term is passed into javascript via C# code: HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallAPI", SearchText);

3) CallAPI function hits the API via $.getJSON & returns a value into the JS callback function [this is already done]

4) Resultant object is returned to the Silverlight/C# page for display in silverlight UI

I can do everything except step 4. How do I get a JSON object from Javascript into C#? I've been working on this for the last few hours, and this is what I thought would do it:

```
ScriptObject myScriptObject = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("CallWordStreamAPI", SearchText);
```

I set a breakpoint in my JS & validated that the object in my return statement is definitely populated with the 20 rows of data, as expected.

I set a breakpoint in my C# (ScriptObject myScriptObject = ....), and myScriptObject is null after the call.
If I set a breakpoint in firebug/chrome dev at the line "return r" (my object), I can see there are 20 items listed in r.data. If I set a breakpoint after the myScriptObject line listed above, myScriptObject is null.

Your help is appreciated.

Scott

Comment: Why are you calling into JavaScript at all?  Why not just code it all in silverlight?

Comment: The API library I have is in JS & the documentation says: "Our formatted responses are designed to work optimally with the JQuery getJSON method."

Comment: Ok but there is no such thing as "jQuery optimal json".  json is a standard and Silverlight has two very good ways to handle json, I would strongly recommend you use them than make blocking calls into JavaScript.

Comment: Well primarily it's for code-reuse in our PHP version of this product. Additionally, this feature-add began with the Google Adwords JavaScript API, which is what got me into JS to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling this from a ViewModel on the server side. I ended up using MVVM Messaging to send the keyword over to my code behind on the client side. I then called my JS function, returned the result, and shot a message back into my view model.

Aside from that, the syntactic issues were resolved here:

[How can I pass a JavaScript function to Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508195/how-can-i-pass-a-javascript-function-to-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

**My Code:**

```
<!-- language: JavaScript -->
function sendText() {
    return "Hi from Javascript!";
}

<!-- language: C# -->
string obj = HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("sendText", null) as string;
txtReturnData.Text = obj;

<!-- language: VB.Net -->
Dim obj As String = TryCast(HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("sendText", Nothing), String)
txtReturnData.Text = obj
```